# Ionic side menu should not allow go back by clicking android back button

Tags: android, button, menu, back, ionic-framework

I'm using this template [ionic starter sidemenu](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu). The app should not allow go back by clicking android back button.

For example, the first page is search.html. When I click "browse" on the menu, the app will go to browse.html. Now, there is no back button on the left-right corner. But if I press back button on the android device (the button at bottom), the app will go back to search.html. The expected behavior should exit the app. Any idea? Thanks a lot.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.search', {
    url: "/search",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/search.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.browse', {
    url: "/browse",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/browse.html"
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the answer in cordova, https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html
`

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           navigator.app.exitApp();
    }, false);
}
```

`